# Reading Torque Wrench instruction

Tags: torque-specification

There is an instruction on this page on how to tighten a bolt on a Chevy Sonic: http://www.csmans.com/engine_mount_bracket_installation-2169.html

It says tighten to 60 Y (45 lb ft) + 45?E0°

Now I can understand 45 lb ft and can convert that to nm which is what I'd use.

But what does all the rest mean?
60 Y and 45?E0°

If I already have the nm value, do I need to be weary about these other values?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you tighten to 60Nm, then, you tighten a further 45 degrees, that is 1/8 of a turn.

Edit: Nick C's comment is correct - I mis-read the post...

Edit 2: The extra load provided by turning so many degrees is to "stretch" the bolt a given amount and that is how it can be specified. Some manufacturers give a torque setting, then a second torque setting, then run the engine and then a third torque setting, or any combination as they specify. One needs to follow the instructions...

Comment: I think the "60Y" should be 60Nm, which is fairly close to 45lb ft (it should be 61Nm, but I suspect whoever wrote the manual rounded down!). I agree with Mike that the rest means +45 degrees.

Comment: Ok that's interesting that they specify a certain torque and then wack on an extra 45 degrees. Since I'm new to this, is that normal? Does it not make sense to just set the torque to what that end result would be with the extra 45 degrees? EDIT: actually from some research it seems it is :)

Comment: Last question, I promise: Regarding the final part of the instruction, "?E0°" Does that have any significant meaning or is that just meaning start at 0 degrees from after you have tightened (which seems very verbose)?

Comment: It looks as if the characters used were not recognised possibly when they converted from one font to another...

Comment: AH ok. That would make sense. It is a weird site. Thanks both of you :)